Is it possible for docker to dynamically create service accounts?
I want all of my self-hosted containers to run as the user ${SLUG} and the group ${GROUP_SLUG}, and if that user/group doesn't exist, it should be created.
There's no need for me to maintain them manually; it's a service account, and its sole purpose for existing is to be run by that container.
Is it possible, using docker compose only, without any additional files, to perform the following:
docker compose up

All services check if ${SLUG} is a known user. If not, create it on the host.
All services check if ${GROUP_SLUG} is a known group; if not, create it on the host.
All services run as the user and group from their env variable.
Any file the container creates will be created using that user.

What I am not looking for:

Additional files to accomplish this.
Special commands before docker compose up

To sum up, I'm looking for a way to make Docker maintain its container's service users (AKA accounts).
Is that even possible?

In your Compose file, just set the user and group IDs you want.  Assuming they're numeric, you can set
user: "${SLUG}:${GROUP_SLUG}"

and run for example
#!/bin/bash
export SLUG="$RANDOM"
export GROUP_SLUG="$RANDOM"
docker-compose up -d

(where, specifically in GNU Bash, the environment variable $RANDOM evaluates to a random integer between 0 and 32767.)
There's no need to create the users in any significant way, either on the host or in the container.
If you only have a user and group name, and the user and group exist on the host already, then you can look them up in the system information.
user: "${UID}:${GID}"

export UID=$(id -u "$SLUG")
export GID=$(getent group "$GROUP_SLUG" | cut -d: -f3)
docker-compose up -d

Just setting user: will usually have the effect you want: the single process that runs in the container will have the specified user ID, which means that any files created by that process will be owned by that user (which may not exist in /etc/passwd either on the host or in the container).
It's possible to build an image so that this doesn't work, and you'd have to edit your Dockerfiles to work around these problems.  Some actions require root access, and won't work if the container runs as a non-root user (can you do this setup in the Dockerfile?); I've seen some setups that require writing back into the application source tree that don't work if the user IDs don't match.  Addressing these will be specific to the image and the problem you're running into.
